# How to approach multiple async requests from back-end in Angular 6?

Tags: javascript, angular, asynchronous

I am new to Angular and having hard time grasping how to deal with async requests.

I have 3 components:
parent - AppComponent
children - LoginComponent,NavbarComponent,DashboardComponent,MainComponent,SidebarComponent

and one AuthService

On pressing "Login" button at the logging component I need to transfer boolean  "true" value to all components.
On pressing "Logout" button at the navbar component I need to transfer boolean  "false" value to all components and set user=null

if true ->

1. set token in localStorage with user ID
2. preform http.get("http://localhost:3000/user/"+id) request to retrieve full user info and inject user info to Dashboard,Main,Sidebar,App and Navbar components.

The problem is that whenever I logout the false/true value updates on all components immediately but the user info does not turn into null unless I refresh the page or send it with router to another component and then return to MainComponent, same thing with new login.

How do I update both user info and status in all components immediately without refreshing the page?

authService:

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { HttpClient } from "@angular/common/http";
import { Router } from "@angular/router";

import { User } from "../models/User";

@Injectable({ providedIn: "root" })
export class AuthService {
  user: User;
  private _url = "http://localhost:5000/user/";

  constructor(private http: HttpClient, private _router: Router) {}

  registerUser(user) {
    return this.http.post<any>(this._url + "register", user);
  }

  loginUser(user) {
    return this.http.post<any>(this._url + "login", user);
  }

  logoutUser() {
    localStorage.clear();
    this._router.navigate(["/"]);
  }

  loggedIn() {
    return !!localStorage.getItem("token");
  }

  getToken() {
    return localStorage.getItem("token");
  }

  getCurrentUser() {
    return this.http.get<any>("http://localhost:5000/shop/current");
  }
}
```

Main/Sidebar component:

```
import { Component, OnInit, DoCheck } from "@angular/core";

import { AuthService } from "src/app/services/auth.service";

import { User } from "src/app/models/User";

@Component({
  selector: "app-sidebar",
  templateUrl: "./sidebar.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./sidebar.component.css"]
})
export class SidebarComponent implements OnInit, DoCheck {
  isSidenavOpen: boolean = true;
  user: User;

  constructor(private _authService: AuthService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    if (this._authService.loggedIn()) this._authService.getCurrentUser().subscribe(res => (this.user = res.user));
    else this.user = null;
  }

  ngDoCheck() {
    if (!this._authService.loggedIn()) this.user = null;
  }
}
```

login:

```
  constructor(private _authService: AuthService, private _router: Router) {}



  // onLoginUser() {
  //   this._authService.loginUser(this.loginUserData).subscribe(
  //     res => {
  //       localStorage.setItem("token", res.token);
  //       localStorage.setItem("user", res.user._id);
  //       this._router.navigate(["/"]);
  //     },
  //     err => console.log(err)
  //   );
  // }
}
```

Comment: where is your user info created?

Comment: I updated the question with the code. New user is created on register component

Answer (score 0):

Use event `EventEmitter` to `emit event` on login, logout etc and listen in each component, that depends on user data.

In service, where you call `logoutUser, loginUser` methods of `AuthService`:

```
// LoginService
userLoggin: EventEmitter<User> = new EventEmitter();
userLoggout: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();

constructor(private _authService: AuthService, private _router: 
Router) {}

loginUser() {
  this._authService.loginUser(this.loginUserData).subscribe(
    res => {
      localStorage.setItem("token", res.token);
      localStorage.setItem("user", res.user._id);
      this.userLoggin.emit(res.user);
      this._router.navigate(["/"]);
    },
    err => console.log(err)
    );
  }

  logoutUser() {
  this._authService.logoutUser().subscribe(
    res => {
      this.userLoggout.emit();
    },
    err => console.log(err)
    );
  }
}
```

Then in component:

```
import { Component, OnInit, DoCheck } from "@angular/core";

import { AuthService } from "src/app/services/auth.service";

import { User } from "src/app/models/User";

import { LoginService } from "src/app/services/login.service";

@Component({
  selector: "app-sidebar",
  templateUrl: "./sidebar.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./sidebar.component.css"]
})
export class SidebarComponent implements OnInit, DoCheck {
isSidenavOpen: boolean = true;
user: User;
loggin$: Subscription;
logout$: Subscription;

  constructor(private _authService: AuthService, private _loginService: LoginService) {
    this.loggin$ = this._loginService.userLoggin.subscribe(user => {
      this.user = user;
    });

    this.logout$ = this._loginService.userLoggout.subscribe(user => {
      this.user = null;
    });
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.loggin$.unsubscribe();
    this.logout$.unsubscribe();
  }
}
```

Comment: but what is I want to use an observable/service to transfer data between siblings and such?

Comment: you can transfer data between parent-child related component via `Input, Output`. I doubt you can do this between siblings.